# webservices change namespace prefix of ASMX Web Service Return

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, namespaces

I am creating webservices and using an overall namespace :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "www.abcdef.com")]
```

when I ask for wsdl it gives me the namespace like `xmlns:abc="www.abcdef.com"`

I would like to change the `abc` prefix to something else. 
Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Why do you want to? The prefix doesn't matter. Also, FYI, if you have to do this sort of thing, it's far easier to do with WCF than ASMX. You should avoid ASMX for new development.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but give it a shot:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://mynamespace/")]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
            [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
            public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns
            {
                get
                {
                    XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                    xsn.Add("me", "http://mynamespace/");
                    return xsn;
                }
                set { /* needed for xml serialization */ }
            }
}
```